# WebJars - Difference between the flavors?

Tags: webjars

I'm planning to use WebJars (through Maven) instead of Bower for my projects.

What's the difference between the NPM, Bower and Classic flavors of WebJars?

My understanding is that since I used Bower, I should probably just use Bower WebJars since I can be sure that those artifacts will be available. Is that the right way to think about this?

Thanks, in advance, for the help.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on where you want the source artifacts to come from.  Classic WebJars usually come from a binary distribution of a library.  Bower and NPM WebJars come from their respective sources.

The Classic WebJars are manually created and published by WebJar contributors.  Bower and NPM WebJars can be published by anyone.

Comment: Can I use dependencies from classic, NPM and Bower in a single project? Is it guaranteed that they are compatible with each other?

Comment: You definitely can use them in the same project.  What kind of compatibility are you looking for?

Comment: I am not expert in JavaScript and build systems such as NPM and Bower. I wonder if their standards to packing things are compatible. And situation when I use dependencies from different worlds would not cause some internal conflicts.

Comment: I can't think of any issues in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

We have chosen for Classic WebJars.

Differences between Classic and NPM that made us go for Classic:

- Classic WebJars have a smaller JAR size ( For example, jQuery 3.4.1 Classic is 308 KB, NPM is 476 KB)
- NPM WebJars expose all sources in the project, which can result in a security problem if there is Javascript code with vulnerabilities in src of that Webjar.